# The DataGridView is loading very slowly. How to optimise adding of rows in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, database, datagridview

**The datagridview is loading very slowly. How can I optimise it?**

The datagridview has 4-5 thousand rows.
I have to generate a datagridview dynamically on a few parameters.(Data from database, No. of columns)

I have to generate the datagridview like  this vertically from the table (id,name,contact) in database..

**Column1**

**id**
**name**
**contact**

Now there can be any number of more empty columns beside **column1.**

Currently I am following this approach.

1. First adding all the empty columns.
2. Then adding three rows in each for loop iteration one row for each (id,name,contact).
3. I am fetching the data from the database and passing it as a `List <string[]>`  to the `GenerateRows` function.

   ```
    private void GenerateColumns(int colLen)
       {
           dataGridViewGenerate.Rows.Clear();
           dataGridViewGenerate.Columns.Clear();

           DataGridViewColumn col0 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
           col0.HeaderText = "Employee No. & Name";
           dataGridViewGenerate.Columns.Add(col0);

           for (int i = 0; i < colLen; i++)
           {
               DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                   {
                       HeaderText =
                           (_sTime.AddDays(i)).Day.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " +
                           (_sTime.AddDays(i)).ToString("ddd")
                   };

               dataGridViewGenerate.Columns.Add(col);
       }


   private void GenerateRows(List<string[]> empList)
       {
           int len = empList.Count;
           for (int a = 0; a < len; a++)
           {
               string[] arr = empList[a];
               //row 1
               var row1 = new DataGridViewRow();
               row1.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell
                   {
                       Value = arr[0]
                   });
               dataGridViewGenerate.Rows.Add(row1);

               //row 2
               var row2 = new DataGridViewRow();
               row2.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell
                   {
                       Value = arr[1]
                   });
               dataGridViewGenerate.Rows.Add(row2);

               //row3

               var row3 = new DataGridViewRow();
               row3.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell
                   {
                       Value = arr[2]
                   });
               dataGridViewGenerate.Rows.Add(row3);
           }
       }
   ```

*I was thinking to make a procedure in sql which will create a table and fill it with the data. Then just assign the datasource to the datagridview.*

Comment: Why would you load 4-5 thousand rows?   How often does a user actually inspect 4-5 thousand rows.  If three columns and can read every cell in 1 second that is still over 3 hours to read.   Page in 100 or 1000 rows at a time.

Comment: I have to create this type of datagrid because data entry work will be done from this grid.

Comment: This will be a very tedious task for the data entry operator.

Comment: Really a 4 thousand row datagridview is your only option for data entry.  And loading very slowly is not a tedious task for the data entry operator?

Comment: Only those data which they are having in hand in their reports will be filled. So I do not know which records will be filled. And so I have to show all the records.

Then the full datagrid will be printed. Even the empty cells. For handwritten data entry of the left out work

Comment: Still, 4 thousand row datagridview is not your only option.  And I serious doubt it is you best option.

Comment: I know that it is not the best option but if I cannot improve the performance then I will divide it into smaller parts similar to pagination. I will try the below given advice and will also see if creating such table in database and assigning it as a datasource will work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is instead of adding rows one by one to the `DataGridView`. I just created a `DataTable` from my data and assigned it as a `DataSource` to the `DataGridView`.

The performance of loading the `DataGridView` improved significantly.

Comment: you have specified that you are adding rows manually, so i assumed that you dont want to use DataBinding. else this would have been my answer. There are even more optimized ways in DataBinding to suspend data update.

Comment: i had 20,000 rows in the DataTable and tried to assign to data source of datagridview and it was extremely slow

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Datagridview repaints whenever you add a row to it,
if you don't mind to use P/Invoke you can try this solution
//to suspend paint

```
SendMessage(Datagridview.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
```

//Your loop to add rows here

then call below method to resume painting

```
SendMessage(Datagridview.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
```

and the P/Invoke declaration should be something like this

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);
private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 0x000B;
```

Comment: I had to call Datagridview.Refresh() after WM_SETREDRAW to get the grid to look fully drawn

Answer (score 0):

Calling Rows.Add() is expensive.  This is a quick-and-dirty change to get around that.

```
private void GenerateRows(List<string[]> empList)
{
    List<DataGridViewRow> rows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
    int len = empList.Count;
    for (int a = 0; a < len; a++)
    {
        string[] arr = empList[a];
        //row 1
        var row1 = new DataGridViewRow();
        row1.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell{Value = arr[0]});
        /* CHANGED to add to List */
        rows.Add(row1);

        //row 2
        var row2 = new DataGridViewRow();
        row2.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell{Value = arr[1]});
        /* CHANGED to add to List */
        rows.Add(row2);

        //row3

        var row3 = new DataGridViewRow();
        row3.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell{Value = arr[2]});
        /* CHANGED to add to List */
        rows.Add(row3);
    }

    /* ADDED all rows at once for performance */
    dataGridViewGenerate.Rows.AddRange(rows.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: What will be better to suspend paint when adding rows or to use addrange. Or should I use both at the same time. i.e suspend paint and addrange.

Comment: This seems easier to me, but you could try each and see what you like better.