# Fastest way of changing rows color of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` control with two methods: Filter() and ResetFilter()

I change BackColor of my `DataGridView`'s rows to blue when I filter my grid.
On ResetFilter I reset every row's BackColor to white.

Here are the codes I have reached so far:

---

```
dgvMain.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToList
     .ForEach(f => f.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White);
```

that takes about 40 to 50 miliseconds, and

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMain.Rows)
{ row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White; }
```

that takes about 30 to 40 miliseconds, which is 25% faster.

---

Is there a faster solution for changind all rows' BackColor? Something like `dgvMain.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White` which does not iterate every row?

Comment: Am very skeptical that `dgvMain.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToList
     .ForEach(f => f.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White);` is 25% faster than traditional foreach !

Comment: What was the row count when you measure these?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Oops I misstyped the order of codes :) sorry, of course traditional foreach is faster than casting to list. Corrected the code. Thanks.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I have about 57,500 rows

Comment: I suspect Paint is called while changing the color. If that's the case see whether [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17555147/2530848) helps you. Prevent redraw of control for sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the iterating all the lines and setting the `BackColor` is a very bad idea. Use `DataGridView` `DefaultCellStyle` property

Comment: I have tried setting `DefaultCellStyle` on `DataGridView` but it does not change the rows' color. Is there any method I should call like Refresh() or Repaint() or something like that?

Comment: I tested it with a simple application and it is working fine, is there any CellFormating/CellPainting you have? Plus it is taking a whole lot of time on my side (Core i5) if I do rows iteration in 57500 lines with 3 text columns.

Comment: Another note, if you have already set some rows' `BackColor` then `DataGridView`'s `DefaultCellStyle` property may NOT work for those lines.